# Setting session duration in ASP.NET MVC application doesn't work in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-ajax

### Defining the problem

I found out that there are two ways to set session duration in ASP.NET MVC application:

1. Setting a value to the `timeout` attribute in the `<sessionState>` field in the `web.config` file.
2. To set `Session.Timeout` property in `Session_Start()` method in `Global.asax.cs` file.

The first method is not working when the `web.config` file is implemented as follows, as mentioned in [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.8), and I get `HTTP 404` error:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="60" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

However, the second method works when implemented in the `Global.asax.cs` file as follows:

```cs
public class ApplicationName : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* Sets the session duration to 60 minutes. */
        Session.Timeout = 60;
    }
}
```

### Notification of Error Code

When I use the first method, I get an `HTTP 404` error when clicking the **"LOGIN"** button on the `/Login/Index` page. Because although the correct username and password are entered, the page is redirected to the `/{token}/Login/LoginControl` page, while the page should be redirected to the `/Profile` page. I have no idea how this behavior occurs.

[image: HTTP 404 Error]

### Related Source Codes

The relevant method in the `LoginController.cs` file and the script defined in the `Login/Index.cshtml` file are as follows:

```cs
public class LoginController : PublicController
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private SessionContext _sessionContext;

    public LoginController(IUnitOfWork uow, IUserService userService) : base(uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _userService = userService;
        _sessionContext = new SessionContext();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoginControl(ELoginDTO login)
    {
        var result = _userService.GetUserByUserName(login.UserName, login.Password);

        if (result != null)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap(result, _sessionContext);
            Session["SessionContext"] = _sessionContext;

            return Json("/Profile", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking the **"LOGIN"** button triggers the `FUNCTION_LoginControl()` script:

```js
function FUNCTION_LoginControl()
{
    var model = { UserName: $("#inputUserName").val(), Password: $("#inputPassword").val() };

    if (model.UserName.trim() != "" && model.Password.trim() != "") 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Login/LoginControl",
            type: "POST",
            data: model,
            success: function (e) {
                if (e != "") 
                {
                    window.location = e;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that when the `cookieless` attribute in the `<sessionState>` field of the **ASP.NET** framework is set true, a unique ID is added to the URL. Therefore, I realized that when I clicked the **"LOGIN"** button, I got an error because the post went to `/{unique-id}/Login/LoginController` while it should have gone to `/Login/LoginController`.

The way to solve this problem is to set the `cookieless` field in `sessionState` in the **Web.config** file to `false`:

```xml
<!-- HttpPost request if "false" is added to the "cookieless" attribute -->
<!-- HttpPost Request: "/Login/LoginController"                         -->
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />

<!-- HttpPost request if "true" is added to the "cookieless" attribute  -->
<!-- HttpPost Request: "/{unique-id}/Login/LoginController"             -->
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="60" />
```