# Once I have created a session variable, can I use it in every way on asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, session

```sh
Session["USER_ID"]  = "1";
```

This is the session variable. I want to know how long the session variable value can be stored.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#session-state

Answer (score 2):

Session duration in ASP.NET is *20 minutes*. There are two ways to change the session duration:

- Setting a value to the timeout attribute in the `<sessionState>` field in the **web.config** file.
- To set `Session.Timeout` property in `Session_Start()` method in **Global.asax.cs** file.

You can change the session duration in the **web.config** file as follows:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You can change the session duration in the **global.asax.cs** file as follows:

```cs
public class ApplicationName : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* Sets the session duration to 60 minutes. */
        Session.Timeout = 60;
    }
}
```

---

###### References

- [Setting session duration in ASP.NET MVC application doesn't work in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350968/setting-session-duration-in-asp-net-mvc-application-doesnt-work-in-web-config)